# "The stream or file "/var/www/html/blog/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: laravel

laravel5.6をブラウザで表示させた時に

```
"The stream or file "/var/www/html/blog/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"
```

上記のエラーが出て、スタート画面が表示されません。
`/storage/log`に`larval.log`ファイルを作成しましたが解決せず、apacheのエラーログにも情報がありませんでした。
本来なら、`larval.log`が自動でできるはずですが、手動で作成しました。

環境はEC2,CentOS7,httpd2.4,php7.1です。

権限は以下のように変更しましたが解決しませんでした。

```
[centos@ip-111-33-22-99 logs]$ ll
合計 0
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0  4月 24 14:12 laravel.log
```

権限の変更をどのようにしたら良いですか。

※追記
現状でディレクトリの権限が以下のようになっています。

blogディレクトリ以下で実行。
    sudo chmod 777 storage
    sudo chmod 777 storage/*
    sudo vi laravel.log
    sudo chmod 777 laravel.log

```
[centos@ip-111-33-22-99 /]$ ll

drwxr-xr-x. 20 root root  278  4月 26 00:32 var

[centos@ip-111-33-22-99 var]$ ll

drwxr-xr-x.  4 centos centos   33  4月 26 00:32 www

[centos@ip-111-33-22-99 www]$ ll

drwxr-xr-x. 3 centos centos 18  4月 26 02:35 html

[centos@ip-111-33-22-99 html]$ ll

drwxrwxr-x. 12 centos centos 4096  4月 26 02:38 blog

[centos@ip-111-33-22-99 blog]$ ll
合計 176
drwxrwxr-x.  6 centos centos     84  3月 14 17:40 app
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 centos centos   1686  3月 14 17:40 artisan
drwxrwxr-x.  3 centos centos     34  3月 14 17:40 bootstrap
-rw-rw-r--.  1 centos centos   1477  3月 14 17:40 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 centos centos 143789  4月 26 02:38 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x.  2 centos centos    247  3月 14 17:40 config
drwxrwxr-x.  5 centos centos     72  3月 14 17:40 database
-rw-rw-r--.  1 centos centos   1150  3月 14 17:40 package.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 centos centos   1088  3月 14 17:40 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxr-x.  4 centos centos    116  3月 14 17:40 public
-rw-rw-r--.  1 centos centos   3622  3月 14 17:40 readme.md
drwxrwxr-x.  5 centos centos     45  3月 14 17:40 resources
drwxrwxr-x.  2 centos centos     75  3月 14 17:40 routes
-rw-rw-r--.  1 centos centos    563  3月 14 17:40 server.php
drwxrwxrwx.  5 centos centos     46  3月 14 17:40 storage
drwxrwxr-x.  4 centos centos     83  3月 14 17:40 tests
drwxrwxr-x. 37 centos centos   4096  4月 26 02:38 vendor
-rw-rw-r--.  1 centos centos    549  3月 14 17:40 webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: ログファイルだけでなく、ログファイルを開くまでに辿る各サブディレクトリのパーミッションも念のため確認してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: 各サブディレクトリのパーミッションも確認しましたが、問題ありませんでした。

Comment: /からログファイルに至る各ディレクトリのパーミッションは、どうなっていたのでしょうか？　そして、それが「問題ない」と判断した根拠は？　こうした情報を質問に追加したほうが良いと思います。　現状がどうなっているのか判らないのに「権限の変更をどのようにしたら」への回答は無理ですから。

Comment: 各ディレクトリのパーミッションを追記しました、blog以下のパーミッションを変更していたので問題ないと判断していました。/以下の権限は確認していませんでしたので追記しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何となくですが、SELinux 周りではないかと思います。

`getenforce` コマンドを実行して `Enforcing` と表示されるなら、
`setenforce 0` で一時的に、SELinux を無効にしてから再度動作をご確認ください。

もし、実際に SELinux が原因であった場合は、

a.（あまり詳しくはないのですが）`chcon` コマンドなどで別途セキュリティ設定を変更して SELinux を有効にしたまま運用するか、

b. `/etc/selinux/config` に `SELINUX=disabled` を記述し、サーバを再起動して恒久的に SELinux を無効にして運用してください。

`getenforce` コマンドを実行して `Disabled` と表示されるならまた別の原因があります。
その場合はすみません。